# "Repair your computer" option missing when loading PERC drivers on Windows 2008 R2 install

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dell-perc

I've got a Dell T310 server for which we have made volume backups of the system drive with Windows Backup.  I'm trying to restore one of these, which means I need to boot from the Windows install CD.  I also know I need to load the PERC storage controller drivers, and have them on a USB.

There is usually splash screen which asks for your language/keyboard settings and then offers options to "Install Now" and "Repair your computer".  Normally, I would click "Repair your computer", which opens the System Recovery dialog.  From there, I would choose the "Load drivers" button, browse to the drivers on the USB and carry on from there.

However, when this server boots, it asks for the language/keyboard settings, then immediately says "A required CD/DVD device driver is missing." and prompts for the driver.  I point it at the PERC drivers on the USB and it continues.

However, at this point, it completely bypasses the "Install Now" / "Repair your computer" splash screen and proceeds to the edition menu and the disk partitioning, as if I had clicked "Install Now".

How do I get it to take the "Repair your computer" branch after taking the device driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that Windows only seems to do this if the USB containing the PERC drivers is inserted into the server *before* the Windows Install environment loads.

If the Windows CD boots without the USB connected, the "Repair your computer" option is shown.  I can then choose to load drivers, insert the USB and point it at the PERC drivers.

Weird, but there you go...

Comment: I also experienced the same problem with a Vista SP2 disk booted from PXE/Serva (which I guess also has something to do with "early disk adding", due to their network share, drivers and whatnot). You can still access the command prompt with `SHIFT+F10` right after having chosen *Install* though. And from there you can launch the recovery console from `X:\sources\recovery\RecEnv.exe`.